# bash script with sed does not work in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed, ubuntu-15.04

I have a bash script to add a few lines of text into the end of a file.

The script works in Ubuntu 14.04 but not in 15.04.

Here is the sed command that I use:

```
    sed -i.bak "\$a<text to add>" </absolute/path/to/file>
```

Tried to check for answers here, but could not found one. Any ideas?

Running the same command in terminal works.

EDIT: - more info

The same script also creates the files before editing them, and the creation works as expected.

File creation code:

```
    if [ -f "$file" ]

    then

        echo "$file found."

    else

        echo "$file not found." 

        touch $file
    fi
```

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: I run it like in 14.04 (where it works)

./name_of_script.sh

And by not working, I mean that the file is not edited (like it was, with the same script in 14.04)

Comment: Not related to the problem but using single quotes around the `sed` script will mean you don't need to escape the `$`.

Comment: Does the `.bak` file get created when you run that script? Add `set -x` to the script and run it again and see what command is actually being run.

Comment: .bak is generated. And now (after I have edited the required changes manually) the editing with sed works.

After running the script for the first time, the file exists but the wanted additions are missing.

Comment: and set -x showed that the sed command was executed as expected.